# Planning for a Covered Deck in the UK

Tags: building-regulations, planning

Do i need permission to build something like this in the UK?

And do i need to follow any building regs?

(I am not in a conservation area)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the Planning Portal, you need planning if the deck is over 300mm high or covers more than 50% of the garden (along with other structures).

([see here](http://www.planningportal.gov.uk/permission/commonprojects/decking/))

It also states that if your deck needs planning, it probably also needs Building Regs approval.